# Modules for media management

Tags: files, media

I am looking at the ability to management off and online video content.
I need to be able to add media using text filters and to search for media within the cms.
What is a good module for a modal style background when playing video?
I need to arrange videos into playlists by artists and create gallerys.

On my research I have come up with the following:

Media
Searching Media
http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_media
http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr
http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_file

http://drupal.org/project/media (for managing media) 
http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery (for managing galleries of images and videos) http://drupal.org/project/mediaelement (for local files) http://drupal.org/project/multiform

More info:http://www.slideshare.net/G_N/drupal-7-media-modules

If you can give me any more information that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also needs views and taxonomy to build the lists.
I'll add also shadowbox or colorbox to play videos in a modalframe.